# Efficiency of localStorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So i basically want to make a blogpost website where you can post mainly text using a page and have another page to show these posts. I want to use local Storage to save the title and the body of the post (or article) as an object. My question is how efficient would that be if the browser has to load like 100 objects (articles) or more.

An alternative method to this would be to save the articles as local files inside the webserver and then load them from there.

Any other ideas on how to make a blogpost system?

```
  // const posts = [
  //   {title: "Post One", body: "This is post one"},
  //   {title: "Post Two", body: "This is post two"}
  // ];

  const posts = [
    // {title: "", body: ""}
  ];

  let name = "obj" + 7;

  var localObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
  posts.push(localObj);

  var article = document.getElementById('post');

  function getPosts(){
    let output = "";
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      output += `<article><h1>${post.title}</h1><p>${post.body}</p></article>`
    });
    article.innerHTML = output;
  }

  getPosts();

  console.log(localStorage);
```

Comment: What does this question mean? There's no absolute scale for efficiency, all you can do is compare efficiency between different methods. What's the alternative to saving in local storage?

Comment: I could save the articles as real text files inside the server and then load them from there

Comment: That will most likely be much slower, since it has to read from the network.

Comment: But the browser can also cache it, which makes it about the same.

Comment: I suggest you not worry about it unless you're talking about megabytes of data. Do whatever is easiest and produces the clearest code.  [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Barmar hmm ok...Thank you alot :D